# Using a .GIF animation as the splash screen in WP7 application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, animated-gif

I have an animated .GIF image that I created with http://ajaxload.info/ and some editing. I would like to set the resulting icon as the splash screen in my app, which can take a few seconds to load.

I don't think that I can set the icon as the SplashScreenImage.**jpg** (GIF != JPG) and I'm not sure how to view the image as a MediaElement either. (I would show the image while the main Canvas was loading.)

DOes anyone have any links/code on how to set both the SplashScreenImage to use the .GIF **AND** how to use the .GIF in a XAML page (from code-behind)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Silverlight doesn't support GIF files. There are a couple of things you could do. Firstly, you could create the same animation in Blend (as a Storyboard). Or, you could display a WebBrowser control which does render GIF files.

As you mentioned, you can't change the SplashScreen image. It has to be a `jpeg` and there's no getting around this. What you could do, however, is have your app load your page with your animation in a PopUp. On a separate thread, you can load your main page and then use a dispatcher to push this on to the UI thread. There is an example of how to do this in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/08/17/creating-a-splash-screen-with-a-progress-bar-for-wp7-applications.aspx).

Comment: I think I may go the way of the WebBrowserTask. Do you know if I can get the WebBrowser to display a local (the aforementioned animated GIF) image?

Comment: To display a local image, you'll have to store the HTML file and Image into IsolatedStorage. The HTML file is a basic HTML document that displays the image. AFAIK, there's no way to simply 'navigate' to the GIF. Example here: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/83180/502219.aspx#502219